# how to filter rows in VisiData based on date column

Tags: date, filter, visidata

I want to filter the rows in my table based on the date.
These are the commands I performed:

go to date column, set as key, `!`, cast to date format `@`. Click `z|` and type `date < "2021-12-01"`.

But 0 rows were selected. How do I perform this action?

Comment: Did you try the way I wrote you? It worked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have

```
id,date
1,2020-12-05
2,2020-07-08
3,2024-12-05
```

open it and set `date` as date using `@`, then `z|` and then something like `date > datetime.date(2020,8,8)`